# Oracle generating schedule rows with an interval

Tags: sql, oracle, date, intervals

I have some SQL that generates rows for every 5 minutes. How can this be modified to get rid of overlapping times (see below)

Note: Each row should be associated with a location_id with no repeats on the location_id. In this case there should be 25 rows generated so the CONNECT by should be something like SELECT count(*) from locations.

My goal is to create a function that takes in a schedule_id and a start_date in the format
'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI'; and stop creating rows if the next entry will cross midnight; that means some of the location_id may not be used.

The end result is to have the rows placed in the schedule table below. Since I don't have a function yet the schedule_id can be hard coded to 1. I've heard about recursive CTE, would this quality for that method?

Thanks in advance to all who answer and your expertise.

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

create table schedule(
       schedule_id NUMBER(4),
       location_id number(4),
       start_date DATE,
       end_date DATE,
         CONSTRAINT start_min check (start_date=trunc(start_date,'MI')),   
       CONSTRAINT end_min check (end_date=trunc(end_date,'MI')),
 CONSTRAINT end_gt_start CHECK (end_date >= start_date),
CONSTRAINT same_day CHECK (TRUNC(end_date) = TRUNC(start_date))
      );

CREATE TABLE locations AS
SELECT level AS location_id,
   'Door ' || level AS location_name,

CASE.    round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'G' 
     END AS location_type

FROM   dual
CONNECT BY level <= 25; 

with
   row_every_5_mins as
   ( select trunc(sysdate) + (rownum-1)*5/1440 t_from,
            trunc(sysdate) + rownum*5/1440 t_to
     from dual
      connect by level <= 1440/5
   ) SELECT * from row_every_5_mins;
```

```
Current output:

|T_FROM|T_TO|
|-----------------|-----------------|
|08162021 00:00:00|08162021 00:05:00|
|08162021 00:05:00|08162021 00:10:00|
|08162021 00:10:00|08162021 00:15:00|
|08162021 00:15:00|08162021 00:20:00|
…
```

Desired output

```
|T_FROM|T_TO|
|-----------------|-----------------|
|08162021 00:00:00|08162021 00:05:00|
|08162021 00:10:00|08162021 00:15:00|
|08162021 00:20:00|08162021 00:25:00|
…
```

Comment: So to "consume" `location_id`'s there should be some order of them on which you want to assign generated lines to locations. And is there any association of `schedule_id` with locations or they should be used in the same manner for any `schedule_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may avoid recursive query or loop, because you essentially need a row number of each row in `locations` table. So you'll need to provide an appropriate sort order to the analytic function. Below is the query:

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     date '2021-01-01'
>     + to_dsinterval('0 23:30:00')
>     as start_dt_param
>   from dual
> )
> , date_gen as (
>   select
>     location_id
>     , start_dt_param
>     , start_dt_param + (row_number() over(order by location_id) - 1)
>         * interval '10' minute as start_dt
>     , start_dt_param + (row_number() over(order by location_id) - 1)
>         * interval '10' minute + interval '5' minute as end_dt
> from a
>   cross join locations
> )
> select
>   location_id
>   , start_dt
>   , end_dt
> from date_gen
> where end_dt < trunc(start_dt_param + 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> LOCATION_ID | START_DT            | END_DT             
> ----------: | :------------------ | :------------------
>           1 | 2021-01-01 23:30:00 | 2021-01-01 23:35:00
>           2 | 2021-01-01 23:40:00 | 2021-01-01 23:45:00
>           3 | 2021-01-01 23:50:00 | 2021-01-01 23:55:00
> ```

**UPD**:
Or if you wish a procedure, then it is even simpler. Because from 12c Oracle has `fetch first` addition, and analytic function may be simplified to `rownum` pseudocolumn:

> ```
> create or replace procedure populate_schedule (
>   p_schedule_id in number
>   , p_start_date in date
> ) as
> begin
>   insert into schedule (schedule_id, location_id, start_date, end_date)
>   select
>     p_schedule_id
>     , location_id
>     , p_start_date + (rownum - 1) * interval '10' minute
>     , p_start_date + (rownum - 1) * interval '10' minute + interval '5' minute
>   from locations
>   /*Put your order of location assignment here*/
>   order by location_id
>   /*The number of 10-minute intervals before midnight from the first end_date*/
>   fetch first ((trunc(p_start_date + 1) - p_start_date + 1/24/60*5)*24*60/10) rows only
>   ;
>   
>   commit;
> end;
> /
> ```

> ```
> begin
>   populate_schedule(1, timestamp '2020-01-01 23:37:00');
>   populate_schedule(2, timestamp '2020-01-01 23:35:00');
>   populate_schedule(3, timestamp '2020-01-01 23:33:00');
> end;/
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from schedule
> order by schedule_id, start_date
> ```
>
> ```
> SCHEDULE_ID | LOCATION_ID | START_DATE          | END_DATE           
> ----------: | ----------: | :------------------ | :------------------
>           1 |           1 | 2020-01-01 23:37:00 | 2020-01-01 23:42:00
>           1 |           2 | 2020-01-01 23:47:00 | 2020-01-01 23:52:00
>           2 |           1 | 2020-01-01 23:35:00 | 2020-01-01 23:40:00
>           2 |           2 | 2020-01-01 23:45:00 | 2020-01-01 23:50:00
>           2 |           3 | 2020-01-01 23:55:00 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00
>           3 |           1 | 2020-01-01 23:33:00 | 2020-01-01 23:38:00
>           3 |           2 | 2020-01-01 23:43:00 | 2020-01-01 23:48:00
>           3 |           3 | 2020-01-01 23:53:00 | 2020-01-01 23:58:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=706d95dc34ca10578cca0b5dfdc0a95f)*

Comment: @Beefstu Please, check the updated version also without recursive query.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop every 10 minutes instead of every 5 minutes:

```sql
WITH input (start_time) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '23:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
         AS t_from,
       start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
         AS t_to
FROM   input
CONNECT BY (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE < INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    LEVEL <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations)
AND    start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE < TRUNC(start_time) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cb842cc24c8a7aea0fcd610c55bc5f76)*

Comment: @MTO thanks for your expertise. Could the loop be modified to stop at SELECT count(*) from locations. I need 1 row for each location but stopping before crossing midnight.Also include a non repetitive location_id. If there are 25 locations and I start at 23:30 I'll only get a few rows as compared to starting at 01:00 I'll get a row for each location. I am not a SQL developer but this seems like I need a LOOP with a stop condition instead of a CONNECT by leve. Am I making a correct assumption. Thanks for your expertise

Comment: @Beefstu Just add the conditions to the `CONNECT BY` clause.

Comment: @MTO almost perfect. How can I get a location_id associated with each row. They can go in order 1-N as long as there are no repeats. In your dbfiddle below I would have location_id 1-3 as we stop before midnight or we run out of location_id. Note the location_id may not be consecutive like in my example. Now back to my regular DBA job.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE is certainly the fastest solution. If you like to get more flexibility for intervals then you can use the `SCHEDULER SCHEDULE`. As drawback the performance might be weaker.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TimestampRecType AS OBJECT (     
    T_FROM TIMESTAMP(0), 
    T_TO TIMESTAMP(0)
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TimestampTableType IS TABLE OF TimestampRecType;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetGchedule(
   start_time IN TIMESTAMP, 
   stop_time in TIMESTAMP DEFAULT TRUNC(SYSDATE)+1) 
RETURN TimestampTableType AS
    
    ret TimestampTableType := TimestampTableType();
    return_date_after TIMESTAMP := start_time;
    next_run_date TIMESTAMP ;
    
BEGIN
    LOOP
        DBMS_SCHEDULER.EVALUATE_CALENDAR_STRING('FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=5;', NULL, return_date_after, next_run_date);
        ret.EXTEND;
        ret(ret.LAST) := TimestampRecType(return_date_after, next_run_date);
        return_date_after := next_run_date;
        EXIT WHEN next_run_date >= stop_time;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN ret;
END;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(GetGchedule(trunc(sysdate)));
```

See syntax for calendar here: [Calendaring Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#BABFBCEF)

Comment: while your solution is eloquent it seems a bit complicated for a novice SQL developer like me. Can it be modified to something like this but exit before crossing midnight select timestamp '2016-01-10 14:00:00' + numtodsinterval(rownum*10,'MINUTE')
    from dual
    connect by level <= 20;

Comment: `start_time` and `stop_time` should be obvious. And an interval of 10 Minutes would be `'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=10;'`