# Oracle modify a recursive CTE to JOIN rows with a table

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, join, common-table-expression

I have recursive CTE, which is working fine. It's designed to generate a numbers of rows based on the count(*) of the locations table, which in this test CASE is 15 or stop before crossing midnight.

My goal is to populate the schedule table. The schedule_id can be hard coded to 1 for now as I plan to wrap this code in a procedure to pass in values.

First, instead of creating rows for a single date I would prefer to use the function generate_dates_pipelined, which creates rows for a range of dates. For each date add the number of seconds ie 83760, which = a time 23:16:00 to create a start_time.

Second, associating a location_id with a date range row being generated.

Note: a unique location_id must be associated with every row. Secondly, though in my test CASE the location_id are consequently ordered  that may not be the case in production. Third, there are only 3 rows instead of 15 because the next row would have crossed midnight.

Thanks in advance for your expertise and to all that answer.

```
Current output:

START_DATE    END_DATE
08192021 23:30:00    08192021 23:35:00
08192021 23:40:00    08192021 23:45:00
08192021 23:50:00    08192021 23:55:00

Desired output:

SCHEDULE_ID LOCATION_ID START_DATE    END_DATE
1 1 08192021 23:30:00    08192021 23:35:00
1 2 08192021 23:40:00    08192021 23:45:00
1 3 08192021 23:50:00    08192021 23:55:00


ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN nt_date PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
BEGIN
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_start);
    EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
    v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END generate_dates_pipelined;
/



create table schedule(
       schedule_id NUMBER(4),
       location_id number(4),
       start_date DATE,
       end_date DATE,
         CONSTRAINT start_min check (start_date=trunc(start_date,'MI')),   
       CONSTRAINT end_min check (end_date=trunc(end_date,'MI')),
 CONSTRAINT end_gt_start CHECK (end_date >= start_date),
CONSTRAINT same_day CHECK (TRUNC(end_date) = TRUNC(start_date))
      );


    CREATE TABLE locations AS
    SELECT level AS location_id,
       'Door ' || level AS location_name,

    CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'T' 
         END AS location_type

    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 15;


     ALTER TABLE locations 
         ADD ( CONSTRAINT locations_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (location_id));


WITH input (start_time) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '23:30' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL
)
SELECT start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE
         AS start_date,
       start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE
         AS end_date 
FROM   input
CONNECT BY (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE < INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    LEVEL <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM locations)
AND    start_time + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '10' MINUTE < TRUNC(start_time) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

Comment: What is the difference between this question and [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68808200/oracle-generating-schedule-rows-with-an-interval)?

Comment: @astentx while I appreciate your solution worked it worked it was too difficult for me to fir me, a novice SQL developer to follow. Whereas MTO solution was nice and and compact. Being a DBA who was thrown this project I suspect I will be responsible for supporting this code. If I can't understand it how can I support it

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to adapt MT0's solution to use `locations` table in the manner of consecutive assignmnent to intervals. Am I right?

Comment: @astenx for example I updated the original question with a new requirement to process a range of dates by calling a function. I would not know where to begin with your sample. I also see adding a PK to the table, which is made up of a schedule_id, location_id, trunc(date) returned by the generate_dates_pipelined function. Lastly I think the code will need to be changed from an INSERT to a MERGE so if run twice for same date it will not get unique violation. If you want to take a shot at modifying MTO sample so its easy for a novice developer like me, I welcome the help

Comment: @abstenx one of the changes is to use MTO code to assign a location_id with a row. I updated the original post with all the required enhancements

Answer (score 0):

One statement to generate the data:

```
     -- The date range
WITH args (start_date, end_date) AS (
         SELECT current_date, current_date + 2 FROM dual
     )
     -- generate entire date range
   , dates (adate) AS (
         SELECT trunc(start_date) FROM args UNION ALL
         SELECT adate + INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM dates, args
          WHERE adate < end_date - 1
     )
     -- generate initial date/times
   , init_datetimes (adatetime) AS (
         SELECT adate + INTERVAL '83760' SECOND FROM dates
     )
     -- generate the rest of the times per date until midnight
   , init_schedules (adatetime, end_time, n) AS (
         SELECT adatetime, adatetime + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, 1 FROM init_datetimes UNION ALL
         SELECT adatetime + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE, adatetime + INTERVAL '10' MINUTE + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, n+1
           FROM init_schedules
          WHERE trunc(adatetime) = trunc(adatetime + 2*INTERVAL '10' MINUTE)  -- stop before midnight
         -- AND n < 10   -- Just for protection
     )
     -- generate some test locations
   , locations (alocation) AS (
         SELECT  1 FROM dual UNION
         SELECT  3 FROM dual UNION
         SELECT  6 FROM dual UNION
         SELECT  7 FROM dual UNION
         SELECT  9 FROM dual UNION
         SELECT 10 FROM dual
     )
     -- add row_number to location list
   , location_list (alocation, n) AS (
         SELECT alocation, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY alocation) FROM locations
     )
     -- Now apply locations to the schedule for each date/time
   , location_dates (alocation, adatetime, end_time, n) AS (
         SELECT alocation, adatetime, end_time, dat.n
           FROM location_list  loc
           JOIN init_schedules dat
             ON loc.n = dat.n        -- one location per row per date
     )
SELECT *
  FROM location_dates
 ORDER BY adatetime, alocation
;
```

The result:

```
loc  date/time         end_time          n
1    08192021 23:16:00 08192021 23:21:00 1
3    08192021 23:26:00 08192021 23:31:00 2
6    08192021 23:36:00 08192021 23:41:00 3
7    08192021 23:46:00 08192021 23:51:00 4
1    08202021 23:16:00 08202021 23:21:00 1
3    08202021 23:26:00 08202021 23:31:00 2
6    08202021 23:36:00 08202021 23:41:00 3
7    08202021 23:46:00 08202021 23:51:00 4
1    08212021 23:16:00 08212021 23:21:00 1
3    08212021 23:26:00 08212021 23:31:00 2
6    08212021 23:36:00 08212021 23:41:00 3
7    08212021 23:46:00 08212021 23:51:00 4
```

Comment: curious why didn't you use my function generate_dates_pipelined and something like this SELECT 
COLUMN_VALUE+
NUMTODSINTERVAL(83760, 'SECOND')
  FROM   TABLE(generate_dates_pipelined(DATE '2021-08-21',DATE '2021-08-30'));

You can get rid of a big chunk of your code? If that's a problem count you help me understand why to better myself. Thanks for your time and patience as I try to become more SQL proficient

Comment: @Beefstu The above was just to show the logic, without extra functions, base or temp tables, etc.  I expect you will replace much of that, like `locations` is probably a base table and you can certainly use your function if you believe that's preferable.  Your question seemed to revolve around "putting all the various logic together".  This was just meant to show how that can be done, with simple SQL, in one statement. I try to stay away from procedural logic, when possible / practical.  That, procedural logic, can often lead to avoidable problems.

Comment: I'm not trying to be critical but the end_time in one row is the start_time of the next. That is not what my posted example does, there is a needed gap.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that.  I was peeking at your initial question and must have locked on to the initial data and didn't notice the gap.  But since I don't use the end time, that can be calculated any way you wish to create the gap, without changing any other logic.

Comment: @Beefstu I've adjusted the SQL above to add a gap. There are other ways to factor this to specify these parameters, for instance, include them once in the args CTE term.

Comment: once the SQL is working I intend on wrapping this in a procedure to pass what ever is needed. This makes code more flexible and can fit others needs. That's one reason I'm a big fan of functions. Can be used by many and if a problem needs to be fixed in only one place. I was  'C' programmer for several years and that method suited me very well. Thanks for your help and expertise. I'll check out your update shortly

Answer (score 0):

Nice and compact. I do cross midnight now as another process was fixed that could not handle that situation. Thanks to all who answered.

```
WITH  params  AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS schedule_id,

TO_DATE ( '2021-08-21 00:00:00'
            , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
            )             AS base_date
    ,    INTERVAL '83760' SECOND          AS offset
    ,    INTERVAL '10' MINUTE           AS incr
    ,    INTERVAL '5' MINUTE         AS duration
    FROM    dual
)
SELECT   p.schedule_id
,               l.location_id
,      p.base_date
,      p.base_date + offset
              + (incr * (ROWNUM - 1)) AS start_date
,      p.base_date + offset
              + (incr * (ROWNUM - 1))
            + p.duration         AS end_date
FROM      locations l
CROSS JOIN params   p
ORDER BY  start_date
;
```